# Read from database and post image

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have the following form:

```
<form action="<?php $self ?>" method="post">
<h2>Shout! </h2>
<div class="fname"><label for="name"><p>Name:</p></label><input name="name" type="text" cols="20" /></div>
<div class="femail"><label for="email"><p>Email:</p></label><input name="email" type="text" cols="20" /></div>
<textarea name="post" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
<input name="send" type="hidden" />
<p><input type="submit" value="send" /></p>
</form>
```

and I have the following table in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `shouts` (
`id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`email` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
`post` TEXT NOT NULL,
`ipaddress` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 );
```

The website i'm using hosts a direct link to the player's avatar in the following way:

```
http://yourwebsitehere/avatarimage.php?username=YourUsername
```

The code above is part of a shoutbox. You fill out the form and the shoutbox shows your message above. What i'm trying to do is add the image of the user that filled out the form next to the message posted.

This is the rest of my code : [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/U4Nmys9N)

How exactly could I make what i'm achieving possible. To read the name the user has filled out from the database and use it in the following way

```
http://yourwebsitehere/avatarimage.php?username=YourUsername
```

and see the image posted near the message.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead `$_POST['name']` there should be `$row['name']` as you are want to use from database query result.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    ....

    $grav_url = "http://game.habboon.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage.php?username=".$row['name'];

    echo('<li><div class="meta"><img src="'.$grav_url.'" alt="Gravatar" /> 
        <p>'.$ename.'</p></div><div class="shout"><p>'.$epost.'</p></div></li>');

}
```